# how do I know if I have the windows 10 update that deletes files

Tags: windows-10

how do I know if I have the windows 10 update that deletes files?
Where would I go and if I have it, how do I uninstall it?

I have so many files...I wouldn't notice if one went missing.

Comment: To expand upon Grawity's good answer:  [How to Find Out Which Build and Version of Windows 10 You Have](https://www.howtogeek.com/236195/how-to-find-out-which-build-and-version-of-windows-10-you-have/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how do I know if I have the windows 10 update that deletes files

If your whole 'Documents' folder is suddenly empty, then you probably have it.

The update is called "Feature update to Windows 10, version 1809" in *Settings → Windows Update → View update history*, and it only affects data during the OS upgrade process, not afterwards.

Since this is a whole-OS upgrade, you'll also see "Version: 1809" in _Settings → System → About" or in the `winver.exe` applet.

> and if I have it, how do I uninstall it?

Uninstalling it won't bring your files back. Keeping it installed won't delete any more files anyway; the problematic part is the upgrade installation, not the final OS itself.

(In fact, if you already installed it without any glitches, then the process of *uninstalling* it – and accidentally re-installing it a few days later – is far more risky.)